# Building a DLL via Maven with mojo-native

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, maven-2, visual-c++

I can build a simple dll consisting of a source file, a header file and a definition but now I am progressing beyond a simple toy dll and working towards something more real (ie: more complex).

The DLL I am trying to compile has 2 source files, 2 headers and the dreaded stdafx pair.

To compile normally you would use /Yc for the pch and /Yu to use it.

How do you specify that with in the constraints of [mojo-native's](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/usage.html) compiler options?

Comment: Did you managed to accomplish the task, if yes- can you tell how? Thanks
Eyal

Comment: No I did not.  In the end we called msbuild via exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, after nearly a week trying to get Maven working I have come to the conclusion that Maven + [Mojo-native](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/) is not possible if you are trying to do any non-trivial C++ development.

I also tried [jade.native](http://www.jfrog.org/sites/jade-plugins/latest/jade-plugin-parent/jade-build-plugin-parent/jade-native-plugin/index.html) fork of [Mojo-native](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/), but that suffered from similar problems which primarily are a lack of documentation followed by a lack of development.

I the end we have knocked that on the head and are now looking at [Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson) for the C++ side of things.